# When I add script code in wordpress' text editor, nothing shows up

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For example this code:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GN64U1L3MB4D

It's a working code as you can see, but when I add it in the "text" page NOT the "visual" tab in wordpress's post's editor, nothing shows up in the preview.

Should I add something or what?

Comment: could you try with html code block from your wordpress editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the "classic", old editor in Wordpress, not the block editor which it has since version 5?

If you *only* add a script in there, i.e. starting with an opening `<script>` tag and ending with a closing `</script>` tag, you won't see anything. You need some HTML code into which the script can put its resulting content, like the first line in the example you linked to. Still, also in this case I would rather use a `div` tag instead of that `<t>` tag which is used in that example. So that HTML line (*outside*  the `script` tag) would be:

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

ADDITION:

The problem is that the WP editor (also the "text view" editor) automatically adds `<p>` tags around each line of code that doesn't start with any other HTML tag (like `<div>`).

So each line of your script code is be wrapped in `<p>...</p>` tags and therefore doesn't work as supposed anymore, since as a script that doesn't make sense anymore. (You can see that in the source code when you inspect the page).

To avoid that, write the whole script into one line, like this:

```
<div id="time"></div>
<script>var theDate = new Date(Date.parse('01/17/2021 20:00 UTC'));document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = theDate.toLocaleTimeString();</script>
```

Now it works (I tried it).

An alternative method is to install the "TinyMCE advanced" plugin which has as an option to *not* insert `<p>` tags automatically.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the old editor. I tried your div line and still showed nothing.

Comment: Did you try to look at the actual page/post (after saving in the editor), not just to the "visual" editor tab?

Comment: Yeah, I preview the post.

Comment: please note the addition to my answer I just posted